# Are there g++ or clang++ debug options to guide variadic templateing

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, c++14, clang++

Is there a way in g++ or clang++ to see *which* instances of function templates are generated and *where* they are generate by which statement?

I try to understand how https://github.com/tomaka/luawrapper/blob/master/include/LuaContext.hpp
works.

Is there a recursive pattern matching compile trace that one can enabled to see template dependencies and how template packs are consumed?

Comment: A simple way would be to modify the code so that the leaf template would cause a compilation error, dumping the usage stack with it. Not quite what you are looking for, but a usefull workaround in a pinch.

Comment: Frank: Nice. Placing the error requires somehow to already understand the structure - but usable when poking around.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [templight debugger](https://github.com/mikael-s-persson/templight#templight-debugger).